# Python - Opening, reading,editing and saving 2010 Excel xls file after choosing it with file picker/file dialog

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, dialog

I want to create an executable program that pops up a file dialog and proceed to open, read, edit and then save the excel file as a new file.

[image]

Currently, I've got the following little script where I'm trying to get the sheet to open/read cell 'F8' and to at least save the excel file but coming up with nothing.

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path 
to the selected file
print(filename)

pip install pyexcel

sheet = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_name = filename)
sheet.content
    print(sheet["F8"])
```

Any suggestions on improving the above script?

Comment: What does "coming up with nothing" mean? Do you get an error? Does the program crash? Does it keep running but it prints the wront data? Also, I don't see anywhere where you're trying to write the data to a file. I just see a print statement. Is there more code you aren't showing us?

Comment: You should only install pyexcel once -- and preferably not by using a script. In other words, you *should* be able to remove this line `pip install pyexcel`, but I realize that won't do much to fix anything here.

Comment: hey @BryanOakley, "coming up with nothing" means when I click on the py file I have saved, nothing is happening. Also, as stated in the description, I currently only have the script where I have attempted to open and read the excel file. There is no more code to show because I am still in the progress of completing the whole script but stuck on this step.

Comment: hi @RonNorris, thanks for the pick up! I'm currently very new to Python and just trying to get as much help as I can. Will make sure to get a more complete script up and running before asking more questions haha